# Syntax error while selecting sequential table in Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql, upgrade

Query:

```
select 
    (@rownum:= @rownum + 1) as row_number 
from 
    (select * from information_schema.tables limit 25) t,
    (select @rownum := (date_format('2018-12-16 00:00:00','%k'))) r;
```

Getting a syntax error in MySQL 8, but not in MySQL 5.7.

Please help.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 supports [ROW_NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800) I would suggest rewriting code to utilize new feature.

Comment: Are you running this code directly in MySQL, or from somewhere else?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Try change `row_number` to something else like `rn` as  Lukas said now is a function of MySql 8

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented already by brilliant SO folks : since version 8.0 of mysql, row_number has become a language keyword, you cannot use it as a column alias.

So you need to change this :

```
select 
(@rownum:= @rownum + 1) as row_number from
...
```

To :

```
select (@rownum:= @rownum + 1) as rn from 
....
```

Another solution is to quote the qualifier, like :

```
select (@rownum:= @rownum + 1) as "row_number" from 
....
```